# Deep search in a JArray

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have the following JSON.

```
[
    ["Identity"], // 0
    ["Contact Information"], // 1
    ["Service Fields"], // 2
    ["Addresses", "Bank Accounts"] // 3
]
```

I would like to write a C# method that uses Json.NET to return the index of the array containing a specific string. For example, if I pass `Bank Accounts` then it will return `3`.

I have tried to use to following code:

```
public byte GetIndex(JArray array, string category)
{
    JArray.IndexOf(array.Descendants().Where(p => p.Contains(category)));
}
```

but unlike `JObject`, `JArray` does not contain a `Descendants()` method, and I am not even sure my lambda expression really express what I want to achieve.

How to accomplish that?

Comment: I think you can do this `array.Children<JObject>().Where(..)`

Comment: JSON structure is fixed or it could change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use instead [`JContainer.DescendantsAndSelf()`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JContainer_DescendantsAndSelf.htm) and [`JToken`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_SelectTokens.htm):

```
var root = (JContainer)JToken.Parse(content);
var descendant = "Addresses";
var query = root
    // Recursively descend the JSON hierarchy
    .DescendantsAndSelf()
    // Select all properties named descendant
    .OfType<JProperty>()
    .Where(p => p.Name == descendant)
    // Select their value
    .Select(p => p.Value)
    // And filter for those that are arrays.
    .OfType<JArray>();
```

Or without [`JContainer.DescendantsAndSelf()`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JContainer_DescendantsAndSelf.htm):

```
var root = JToken.Parse(content);
var descendant = "Addresses";
var query = root
    // Recursively descend the JSON hierarchy using the JSONpath recursive descent operator "..", and select the values of all properties named descendant
    .SelectTokens(string.Format("..{0}", descendant))
    // And filter for those that are arrays.
    .OfType<JArray>();
```